# Changing the URL Extension

Tags: asp.net, url, file-extension

I had developed a Web application in Asp.net. When am using the Application over IIS, the file extension as.aspx is visible. Is it possible to hide it (or) rename it....Thankx in advance.

Comment: This question maybe help u! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240382/how-do-you-change-the-extension-that-net-pages-will-run-under

Answer (score 1):

For .NET framework 4.0+, try the following rule in `web.config` (inside `<system.webServer>`):

The first will redirect URLs using the old format, to remove the `.aspx` extensions. You should of course update your links as well - eventually you won't need this.

The second rule rewrites URLs internally to add `.aspx` behind the scenes.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectOldFormat" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="InternallyAddAspx" enabled="true">
            <match url=".*" negate="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
        </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: <system.webServer>. Updated the answer with that :)

Comment: Got Error while trying to use the code <system.webserver><rewrite></rewrite></system.webserver>.... as Element has invalid child elements.

Comment: @MattDavies this solutiion is for <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>

Comment: What version of .NET and IIS are you guys using? We might need to tailor this more specifically.

Comment: Framework 3.5. IIS i think does not matters. I think you must refer to your post that solution refers to .net 4.

Comment: In fact you have to iclude to your post.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Framework 3.5 or earlier, you can accomplish this using routing. Try the following solution:

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/294_Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs_Using_Routing_in_ASPNet_35.aspx